# iptcembed return false

Tags: php, image, metadata

My code calls iptcembed() to set some image metatags, but for some reason iptcembed() returns false for some of my images.

For other images, iptcembed() works perfectly fine.

I can't find any differences between the images. All of them are .jpg images.

Any idea why iptcembed() might return false for some of the images?

Using error_get_line(), I have found out that I get the following error message when iptcembed() returns false:

```
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => iptcembed() [function.iptcembed]: Unable to open abe.jpg [file] => C:\projects\imagemetadata\Image Metadata\Image Metadata\iptc.php [line] => 110 )
```

(I'm using the iptc code from http://php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php, user note from september 2008)

Thanks a lot,
Louisa

Comment: Seems like iptcembed can't find or open the file. Might it be any file permission problems?

Comment: I don't think it's something with permissions as the code following the iptcembed() command deletes the file.

`if(!function_exists('iptcembed')) return false;
  $mode = 0;
  $content = iptcembed($this->binary(), $this->file, $mode);
  
  if($content == false)
  {
   $err = $this->error_get_line(__LINE__-4);
   print_r($err);
  }
  else   
  {   
   $filename = $this->file;
   
   @unlink($filename); #delete if exists
   
   $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
   fwrite($fp, $content);
   fclose($fp);
  }`